# Which persons, in both files, have names ending in a?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNl9v.png)> **grep *a results1.txt**

i have already tried it but it didn't work .
i have another question that is

> Which persons, in both files, have a first name with exactly three letters?

Comment: start with posting your `results1.txt`. Also, *in both files* means 2 files. Post the fragments from 2 files

Comment: **Yngve Johanson 10 11 8 Ingrid Lindgren 8 13 13 Kjell Djurstedt 12 12 12 Lennart Andersson 9 10 13 Elisabeth Björklind 15 12 10 Mama mama 10 20 30  **       I have this file it ends with numbers .. then what can i do?

Comment: do you still need this *a first name with exactly three letters?* There's only one line that fits that requirement and it's `Suv Tidblom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep a$ results1.txt`

http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html:

$ (Question)    =   match expression at the end of a line, as in A$.

Comment: Yngve Johanson      10  11   8
Ingrid Lindgren      8  13  13
Kjell Djurstedt     12  12  12
Lennart Andersson    9  10  13
Elisabeth Björklind 15  12  10
Mama mama           10  20  30                                                                                                           I have this file it ends with numbers .. then what can i do?